# Return Dictionary with Object Value in OrmLite

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Is it possible in ServiceStack OrmLite to return a key-value dictionary with a value that's an object (class or anonymous type)?

For example:

```
var q = db.From<Customers>()
          .Select(c => new { c.CustomerId, (c.FullName, c.Address) });

var list = db.Dictionary<int, object>(q);
```

In this case, I want the `Dictionary` item key to be `CustomerId` and value to be an object with two properties: `FullName` and `Address`.

I will be serialising the dictionary to JSON using Newtonsoft.Json for client-side lookup via key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t do a Tuple projection in an SqlExpression, you’d use it to select the columns you want:

```
var q = db.From<Customers>()
      .Select(c => new { c.CustomerId, c.FullName, c.Address });
```

Then you can use [C# 7 Tuple syntax to select custom columns](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#c-7-value-tuples), e.g:

```
var rows = db.Select<(int id, string name, string address)>(q);
```

Comment: Thanks Demis. Besides tuples, is there any way to have OrmLite return a dictionary with a key and multi-field object value? Update: something like this `var list = db.Dictionary<int, (string, string)>(q);` doesn't work either.

Comment: @Nick See the OrmLite project page for different ways to select Dynamic ResultSets, there’s also db.Lookup which is similar but for your specific use-case the most flexible option is to populate the dictionary with how you want in your own code.

Comment: Yeah I had a look at the GitHub page, but couldn't find anything relevant to my use-case. I was hoping to avoid creating a custom dictionary as it will involve an extra iteration over the result-set, but I guess that's the only option for now. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Nick that iteration over an in memory collection is irrelevant in the context of an I/O call.